# Передать в делегат Func динамический тип

Tags: c#

В качестве аргумента у метода нужен делегат Func в котором первый параметр - Type не известен:

```
class MyClass
{
  void myMethod(Func<?, bool> func){
    //...
  }
}
class OtherClass : MyClass
{
  int par1;
  string par2;
  //...
}
```

Что-бы можно было воспользоваться мои методом следующим образом: `OtherClass.myMethod(o=>o.par1 == 10)`

Именно класс **"OtherClass"** должен как-то попасть как аргумент в **Func**.

Comment: generic скорее всего поможет: `void myMethod<T>(Func<T, bool> func){`

Comment: а, стоп, что-то странное ты хочешь. А зачем тебе нужен тип наследника в метод базового класса?

Comment: Я конечно могу использовать dynamic, но хочется что бы VS понимала и вываливала все поля, класса OtherClass, как это делается например в linq: objects.Where(o=>o.par==...)

Comment: Вообще мне нужно работать с чужим классом учитывая переданное условие.

Comment: тогда в принципе generic попробуй

Comment: судя по примеру использования и отсылке к ` objects.Where(o=>o.par==...)` тут нужен скорее метод расширения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае метод стоит вынести из базового класса в расширение:

```
static class MyClassExtensions 
{
    public static void MyMethod<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> condition) where T : MyClass
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Если принципиально чтобы метод находился именно в самом классе (например, ему требуется доступ к приватным полям) - надо делать нетипизированный метод в классе и типизированный в расширении:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethodImpl(Func<MyClass, bool> condition)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

static class MyClassExtensions 
{
    public static void MyMethod<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> condition)
        where T : MyClass
        => obj.MyMethodImpl(x => condition((T)x));
}
```

"Скрыть" MyMethodImpl из контекстной подсказки можно сделав его приватным, а вызывать тогда его придется через еще один статический метод:

```
class MyClass
{
    private void MyMethodImpl(Func<MyClass, bool> condition)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static void MyMethod<T>(T obj, Func<T, bool> condition)
        where T : MyClass
        => obj.MyMethodImpl(x => condition((T)x));
}

static class MyClassExtensions 
{
    public static void MyMethod<T>(this T obj, Func<T, bool> condition)
        where T : MyClass
        => MyClass.MyMethodImpl(obj, condition);
}
```

Или же, если вы делаете библиотеку, можно обойтись internal.

Comment: Сути всё же не уловил. Как всё-таки получить доступ к OtherClass. Ведь в condition должны потроха OtherClass доступны.Напишите пример использования пожалуйста.

Comment: @Aleman внешнему коду будут доступны публичные члены из OtherClass во всех трех вариантах. К приватным членам вы доступ не получите никак кроме рефлексии, на то они и приватные.

Comment: Это работает только при создании экземпляра, статика почему-то не работает...

Comment: @Aleman что именно не работает?

Comment: При вызове OtherClass.MyMethod(.. Он требует 2 параметра, т.е он подставляет не из расширении, а из оригинального класса.

Comment: @Aleman а откуда у вас в базовом классе метод MyMethod? Посмотрите примеры кода еще раз, по-внимательнее. Я такого метода в базовом классе не писал.

Comment: Посмотрел, скопировал и пробую использовать. Вот скрин: https://hkar.ru/QzOy

Comment: @Aleman а зачем вы так пишите? Ваш исходный вопрос был про метод экземпляра, такие методы вызываются не у класса, а у объекта. Где в вашем коде есть объект типа OtherClass?

Answer (score 1):

это неправильная архитектурная поведение но можно вот так сделать.

```
     class MyClass<T>
     {
         void myMethod(Func<T, bool> func)
         {
             //...
         }

     }

     class OtherClass : MyClass<OtherClass>
      {
              int par1;
              string par2;
      }
```

или ассоциацию можно использовать.